# Gram Schmidt-The arts behind it

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gram-schmidt

One simple question,why Gram-Schmidt works? Honestly, I can't crack the key for this question given by my lecturer,so if you guys don't mind to share some thought, it will be very helpful.

Saludos

Comment: Well, you can't crack that without own effort. Just take your favorite skalar product and try it out, it's rather convincing. As long as you have a reasonable basis, and not too many vecors. Otherwise, it's usually a disaster, numerically.

Comment: Given a basis $\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ what the process does is, one by one, "opening" the vectors so that they are orthogonal to each other, generating the same space.

Comment: you can prove by induction that the Gram-Schmidt procedure produces orthonormal vectors. If the list have the dimension of the space then, obviously, it is an orthonormal basis of this space.

Comment: Your instructor asked you this question because he's interested in knowing how well *you* can synthesize different parts of linear algebra (projection, linear combinations, orthogonality, etc.).  There's no "key" other than the one in your own head.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary (and maybe sufficient) that you have clear the conceprt behind **first step**.

Let's consider two linearly independent vector and then subtract from the second its vector projection on the first one. In this way you obtain 2 orthogonal vectors.

Then consider a third linearly independent vector and subtract from it its vector projection on the two orthogonal vectors you have. In this way you have obtained 3 orthogonal vectors and so on.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a given vector $v$ and a given direction. Let $u$ be any vector is the given direction. Is it possible to decompose $v$ into two orthogonal vectors, one of which is in the direction of $u?$ The answer is  yes. Simply find the  projection of $v$ over $u$ and and subtract it from $v$. Now Your $v$ looks like the hypotenuse of a right triangle with the base in the direction of $u$. The Gram-Schmidt process generalizes this concept step to higher dimensions.